# Antonym of "outlier" suitable for statistics parlance?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

For use in the example sentence:

> After the outliers had been removed, the **...** were grouped with a disjoint set (aka. Union-Find).

I lean towards [***inliers***](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3464), but this seems wrong given the linked definition.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Norms?  Standards?  Remaining Xs?

Comment: The remaining elements were grouped. You do not give us enough information. Sets have members or elements, right? Perhaps you could be clearer.

Comment: I think this should be migrated to [Math.SE] since you specifically want it for "statistics parlance".

Answer (score 1):

Sean,

TBQH, given that it is 2018 and statistical discussions are more commonplace (people were not discussing Gladwell or Piketty when they spoke Latin), a neologism such as **inlier** would be acceptable.

And interestingly enough, "inlier" may have been been in use [for ~150 years](https://www.etymonline.com/word/outlier). (see related entries)

Answer (score 1):

"... the remainder were grouped..."

You also might want to use cluster as a term for the grouping too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good English word of Latin origin for what is left over after something has been removed: residuum. It has the advantage over 'inliers' of not implying that what is left is more true than the data you had to start with - a fact always to be borne in mind when one is tempted to censor one's data.

Comment: Except I'd be more inclined to refer to the outliers as the residua of the process. And *decantant* doesn't seem to be used the way the OP wants.

Comment: @PhilSweet Really! That sounds odd. Can you cite any references to that usage?

Comment: He has some existing (disjoint) set R. He is comparing his test set to R and R is absorbing qualifying elements and not absorbing the outliers. Metaphorically, the stuff remaining outside R is the residual.

Comment: While your average statistics reader may have a large vocabulary at their disposal, I think it will rarely extend to such obscure latin terms